# Textfield is null even when there is value in it

Tags: android, android-edittext, fragment

I am using fragment have to Textfield in it. one is for name and other is phone number. Validation for both work just fine. But when I Toast it says null/false.

`EditText tPername = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtPer);`

This is xml

```
            <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtPer"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"/>
```

When I Toast R.id.txtPer it says null.
This is my java code

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_customer, container, false);
    view.findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            doAdd(view);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
public void doAdd(View view) {

    String MobilePattern = "[0-9]{10}";

    EditText tPername = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtPer);
    EditText tMobnum = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtMob);
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(tPername.getText().toString())) {
    tPername.setError("Please fill this field");
    return;
   } else if (!tMobnum.getText().toString().matches(MobilePattern)) {
        tMobnum.setError("Mobile number must be entered 10 digits only");
        return;
    }
```

}

Comment: show your java code

Comment: OK I will use Log. But R.id.txtPer always says null

Comment: post your java code

Comment: You need to post your java code

Comment: Here is the java code above

Answer (score 0):

```
type a (EditText tPername = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtPer);)

in the onViewCreated

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

EditText tPername = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtPer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String name= tPername.getText().toString();
```

This solved my problem.Thanks